# ASP.net MVC partial view form requiring property from parent model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

I'm trying to structure my controllers and views in such a way that all of my views are strongly typed and I am not using ViewBag. I have a base view model that I inherit from, create one "container" view model per view, plus a view model for each form.

For this example let's focus on a Zone entity that can consist of a group of countries (might be used for calculating shipping, VAT, etc):

```
public class BaseViewModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string MetaDescription { get; set; }
    public string CanonicalUrl { get; set; }
    public Website Website { get; set; } // class that contains properties like site name, base url, use ssl, etc
}

public class ZoneCreateForm
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.MultiLineText)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int[] CountryIds { get; set; } // Selected country ids
}

public class ZoneCreateViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Country> Countries { get; set; } // All countries. Used to create a dropdown list to select from

    public ZoneCreateForm CreateForm { get; set; }
}
```

I was trying to limit my "form models" to only the fields that are posted to the form. This helps scaffolding by eliminating the properties from the base model, and AutoMapper in the controller action on the post.

However, in this example I need access to the `Countries` property of the parent model in order to create the drop down list of all the countries.

The way I see it, I have some options:

1. Give in and stuff the countries into the ViewBag so they are accessible from the **CreateForm** partial view.
2. Make the Countries part of the `ZoneCreateForm` view model and use [Bind(Exclude="Countries")] on the controller action to avoid over-posting
3. Something else I'm not thinking of?

Is there a "standard" way of handling this? Most of the examples I've seen strewn across the web are using the domain models, rather than view-specific models with any inheritance and sub-models. Whenever they have additional data needs they just stuff it into ViewBag, which seems dirty to me.

Comment: Why cant you just populate the Counties property that is part of the ZoneCreateViewModel in the controller and render a drop down list from it on the view's that require, and leave it as null on those that do not?

Comment: The form partial view that needs the countries is based off of the `ZoneCreateForm` which doesn't include the list of countries. I think what I'll end up doing is adding `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Countries` and `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> States` to the `ZoneCreateForm` model and use `public ActionResult Create([Bind(Exclude="Countries,States")]ZoneCreateForm form)` for the action method.

Answer (score 2):

What version of MVC you are using? With the MVC6 you can add dependency injection in view and not have this in your model.

Example:

- [Getting Lookup Data Into You View ASP.net MVC 6 Version](http://blog.simontimms.com/2015/06/09/getting-lookup-data-into-you-view/)
- [Dependency injection in ASP.NET 5](http://gunnarpeipman.com/2015/08/dependency-injection-in-asp-net-5/)

Comment: I'm using MVC5 :(  Very interesting article on injecting in MVC6 though. I wasn't aware of that. He started off with the exact issue I am describing. I kind of feel like it is leaking controller concerns into the view though.